# Rails 4: converting Escaped Unicode to utf-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, unicode, datatables, ajax-request

I have looked everywhere and googled / stackoverflown, but I just can't find a solution. Please help!

I am using jQuery datatables with columnFilter plugin for an Ajax-sourced table. I am trying to implement a `select` filter with `multiple` option.

The problem is that the options to this contain special characters (Chinese, German, Japanese, Russian etc.). Now
when the `multiple` option is off. The json request is processed without any problems (I get the exact characters, that are submitted and I use them to fetch the required db entries, that include entries in all those languages). However, when the `multiple` option is on, all special characters get escaped.

Basically the option

> "Chinese Simplified (简体中文)"

processed as json becomes

> "Chinese%20Simplified%20%28%u7B80%u4F53%u4E2D%u6587%29"

In the backend I am using the following code:

```
.
.
.
    if params[:sSearch_2].present?

      langs = get_items_from_multiple(params[:sSearch_2])

      unless langs == []
        cards = cards.where(:language => langs)
      end

    end

.
.
.
  def get_items_from_multiple(request)
    require "cgi"

    itemList = request.match(/\^\((.+)\)\$/)   #Extract request from within ^( )$

    if itemList.nil?
      itemList = []
    else
      itemList = itemList[1].split("|")        #Split options
      escaped = []
      itemList.each do |item|
        escaped << CGI.unescape(item).gsub("\\", "") #trying to unescape
      end
      itemList = escaped
    end

    itemList

  end
```

Now the `CGI.unescape...` part only unescapes punctuation. Resulting in something like:

> "Chinese Simplified (%u7B80%u4F53%u4E2D%u6587)"

Leaving me with un-unescaped (sorry for that) Chinese characters.

What I would like to achieve is pass an array of fully unescaped strings as `langs` into this query:

```
cards = cards.where(:language => langs)
```

as they are recorded in the db, to fetch the items in all the selected languages.

I cannot find a ruby/rails method, that might do that. And I am unaware of the proper way to substitute the preceding `%` with `\` without escaping the latter (so as to get something like `"\u7B80"` which turns seamlessly into `"简"`.

Any ideas?

Comment: The string is `Chinese Simplified (简体中文)`. It's all fine when it's unicode-escaped. Where do you want to display/store it? Store it in DB? Then, store it as it is. Why do you want to unescape it? Just because it is escaped in displaying? Where is it displaying?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Apparently I didn't make myself clear: In my db all the data is stored in the unescaped format like this: 
`Chinese Simplified (简体中文)`. I'm using the string in the `ActiveRecordModel.where(:language => the_string_in_question)` Which only returns entries that match exactly.
Basically I need unescaping, because I don't want to generate a query in the form of `ActiveRecordModel.where("language like :selectedSearchOption1 or language like :selectedSearchOption2 or etc...", selectedSearchOption1: "#{unescaped_string1}", selectedSearchOption2: "#{unescaped_string2}", etc)`

Comment: To be more precise: I'm actually passing an array of exactly matching strings to `...where(:language => selectedOptionsAry)`. So as to filter all the selected ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assign

```
str="Chinese%20Simplified%20%28%u7B80%u4F53%u4E2D%u6587%29"

new_str=Rack::Utils.parse_query(URI.unescape(str))
```

OR

```
new_str=Rack::Utils.parse_query(Utils.unescape(str))
```

Hope it should do the needful.

Comment: Thank you, will check asap and feedback

Comment: I have tried your solutions. There is some progress - instead of doing nothing about the special chars, rails now admits the %-encoding in my string, throwing, however, the following exception (copied from WebBrick)
`ArgumentError (invalid %-encoding (Chinese Simplified (%u7B80%u4F53%u4E2D%u6587)))`